# How to give relative path for destinations of plugins (executable bundles) packagemaker?

Tags: packagemaker

How to give relative path of destination of bundles while creating package from packagemaker?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but maybe

```
cp -R ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.bundle ${SRCROOT}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.bundle
```

is what you want? `${SRCROOT}` might be what you're looking for.

I use this in my build script (for [this bundle](https://github.com/pooriaazimi/BetterDictionary/)) to copy the created bundle to my source directory (for easier access, and also because I want to `zip` it).